# Image (area) map hover - how to with jquery?

Tags: jquery, image, dictionary, hover, area

sorry but I do not have much knowledge on jquery, I think it is very simple solution for someone who has. I tried to implement this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QW2xd/) for all day, but I just cannot get it to work.

My site is [here](http://www.beawareof.info/supernova/pritlicje.php) and my problem in the left category menu- sorry for the slovenian naming- under "TRGOVINE"- (moda, šport, obutev,..etc.) I want this links to highlight the specific shop in on the area map, where hover is already implemented. So, I want effect on hover over "Moda", to highlight all the shops under category "Moda".

Which script do you recommend? And what id's and classes should I assign to the links and images.

Comment: Data e ora: 25/09/2012 17:33:11
Errore: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [type="text/javascript"],not([type])
File sorgente: http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js
Riga: 2, validate your xhtml and js then give it a go

Comment: sorry but I do not understand.. the responsible script for hover effect is script.js

Comment: What's wrong with the functionality of the jsFiddle you posted? I tweaked it a little bit here http://jsfiddle.net/QW2xd/13/ but it seems like it works as expected.

Comment: MP, max4ever's comment was suggesting that you should fix the error in the JavaScript/debug console before continuing further.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some hysteresis I would recommend checking out [the hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html). You might also want to check out [this map hilight plug](http://davidlynch.org/blog/2008/03/maphilight-image-map-mouseover-highlighting/) [(demo here)](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html).